# No errors in javascript but it does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use PHP to echo back javascript and html.
I am trying to send two values to another PHP file using AJAX with the code echoed back from the original echo.
An example of this javascript is:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#join_testtest').on('cick', function() {
                        var clubName = $('#join_name_testtest').val();
                        var userName = $('#userName_join').val();

                        $.ajax({
                                  url: 'joinClub.php',
                                  method: 'POST',
                                  data: {
                                      clubName: clubName,
                                      userName: userName
                                  },
                                  success: function(response){
                                        $('#response_join').html(response); 
                                    }, 
                                    dataType: 'text'
                               });

                    });
                });

            </script>
```

Here is the html code that corresponds to the above example:

```
<input id='join_testtest' type='button' value='join testtest'>
<input type='text' id='join_name_testtest' style='display:none;' value='testtest'>
<input id='userName_join' style='display:none;' value ='1'>
```

There are no errors in the console. The PHP will either exit with keyword success or fail but nothing is printed in #response_join. Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Did you try giving the `ajax` method an error handler, or look at your browser's network tab to see the response status?

Comment: im not sure how to do that- im very new to coding

Comment: @gurnii Do you know what browser developer tools are?

Comment: @Tyler no i do not

Comment: @gurnii All modern browsers have something called developer tools. They provide a lot of information about what's going while the website is running, such as a console where javascript errors and similar things would be outputted. I believe F12 is the common shortcut to bring up developer tools.

Comment: @gurnii In addition to the console, you can also view files that the client receives, such as the javascript files and add break points. So you can watch what is happening in your javascript as it runs and look at what is being returned.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @MadeOfAir That looks like a really nice tutorial. I just skimmed through it and still learned a few things myself. XD

Comment: @gurnii If i understand correctly, you are expecting your PHP page to echo out a html table right? Can you try echoing out pure text: `echo "some text";` . Please mention if you see the text or not.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your click before your arbitrary function was spelled wrong. I changed Ajax so after it is finished it should log an error. If you’re not getting the error logged, then it’s not getting to the Ajax methods.

I also added FormData object as well.

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('#join_testtest').on('click', function() {
            var clubName = $('#join_name_testtest').val();
            var userName = $('#userName_join').val();

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('clubName', clubName);
            formData.append('userName', userName);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'joinClub.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'text'

            }).done(response => {

                $('#response_join').html(response); 

            }).error(error => {
                console.log(error);

            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

If you can post some more of the code, I think we’re missing something between the DOM elements and jQuery.

Are you using an old version of JQuery?

Where is this script located? At the top or bottom of the page? And is it above or below the jQuery inclusion?

You can also download and test with [Postman](http://getpostman.com)

You can also change `$('#join_testtest').on('click', function() {`

with

```
$('body').on('click', '#join_testtest', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: i tried it and nothing happened. Also no error was logged.

Comment: @gurnii Click was spelled wrong also on the original code. Just thought I’d mention that here. How is PHP returning the response? Are you setting the headers in PHP?

Comment: the #userName_join is just a text input that is hidden. the other two are in a form. #join_testtest is a type button and it initiates the javascript. the way my PHP works is that it echoes back a table. There are something like 15 rows, but this number can change. The database has an array of club names. These club names are inserted in the echo. Therefore, for each of the 15 rows, there are 15 different sets of the two inputs in the form and 15 unique javascript functions.

Comment: also my JQuery inclusion is below the example js.

Comment: Move the Jquery Inclusion above the example js. Put a `console.log('I was clicked')` inside the arbitrary click method.

Comment: i moved the inclusion above the js, but the console.log in the arbitrary method is not printed. Im looking over my code for any syntax errors.

Comment: @gurnii Where are you looking to check if the console.log was printed?

Comment: @Tyler I am looking in the console when i inspect my website.

Comment: @gurnii Alright, just being sure. :) Didn't want to go a wild goose chase by looking at the wrong areas.

Comment: @Tyler do you think that echoing js through PHP is a bad idea? Could that be causing problems

Comment: @gurnii Whether or not it's bad practice, I'm not entirely sure; however, I would avoid it simply because javascript should be in javascript files usually.

Comment: Can you push your code to GitHun and message me the link? I might be able to help early morning. Up to you.

Comment: @Stackout OP wasn't aware of browser devtools, I'd be surprised if he/she is aware of source control

Comment: @Stackout I was able to get it to work, but only when the name from the database contains no spaces. "testtest" works but "test test" doesn't. How can I deal with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Below code working fine to me.Hope this will be helpful.

```
<div id="response_join"></div>
<form method="POST">
    <input type='text' id='join_name_testtest' hidden value='testtest'>
    <input id='userName_join' hidden value='1'>
    <input type='button' id='join_testtest' value='join testtest'>
</form>`
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#join_testtest").on('click', function () {
            var clubName = $('#join_name_testtest').val();
            var userName = $('#userName_join').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'joinClub.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    clubName: clubName,
                    userName: userName
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#response_join').html(response);
                },
                dataType: 'text'
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```